# Floats not evaluating as negative (Python)

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, floating-point, negative-number

I am trying to delete floating point values in a list that are negative. The original list with all of the values looks like this:

```
[
    0.030079979253112028,
    -0.006015995850622406, 
    -0.08920269709543568,   
    -25.72356846473029,
    -9.770807053941908, 
    -66.38340248962655, 
    -188.7778008298755,
    -165.95850622406638,
    99.99,
    33.81404564315352,
    0.1742564315352697,
    -0.00560109958506224,
    -0.008297925311203318,
    -1.4044238589211617
]
```

After I run a `for` loop that says `if num<0: list.remove(num)` the list looks like this:

```
[
    0.030079979253112028,
    -0.08920269709543568,
    -9.770807053941908,
    -188.7778008298755,
    99.99,
    33.81404564315352,
    0.1742564315352697,
    -0.008297925311203318
]
```

So some of the negative vlues, like `-66.383...` got deleted, but others didn't. Why is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are iterating over and mutating the list which means you end up removing the wrong elements, you can  use [reversed](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reversed):

```
for num in reversed(lst):
    if num < 0:
        lst.remove(num)
```

Or make a copy:

```
for num in lst[:]:
    if num < 0:
        lst.remove(num)
```

You can also use a list comp to modify the original list:

```
lst[:] = [num for num in lst if num >= 0]
```

Comment: @Syd, it is a reverse iterator, I added a link to the docs in the answer, removing elements from the list means you change what elements a the pointers were pointing to when you started the iteration.

Answer (score 2):

To provide an illustration in what is happening here and why mutating a sequence you are currently iterating over is a bad idea:

```
1, -1, -1, 0
^ # this is your iterator starting at the beginning

1, -1, -1, 0
    ^  # after on step we are here your function has deemed this value unworthy 

1, _, -1, 0
   ^  # the value has been removed but we can't have an empty space so everything gets moved forward

1, -1, 0
    ^  # now everything has shifted forward but our iterator has not moved.

1, -1, 0
       ^  # Our iterator goes to the next step without ever having evaluated the value that got shifted in to the removed values place.
```

You will notice the pattern in you results that the negatives that remain in your list are always preceded by another negative originally. It's better practice to create a new list of leaving out the values or objects you don't need:

```
new_list = [x for x in old_list if foo(x)]
```